# Composition operator on $L^p$ spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu ) $ be a measure space. Let $f:X \to X$ a function with the following property: $f(B),f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{B}$ for all $B \in \mathcal{B}$. Moreover,for some $c >0$, $f$ satisfies $\mu(f(B)) \ge c\mu(B) $ for all $B \in \mathcal{B}$.

I'm trying to prove that the composition operator $T_{f}: \phi \mapsto \phi \circ f$ is continuous, where $\phi \in L^{p}(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$. Any hint ?

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_1,\ldots, A_n$ be a measurable partition of $X$ and let $B_i=f^{-1}(A_i)$, so $B_1, \ldots, B_n$ is also a measurable partition of $X$. Moreover, $f(B_i)\subset A_i$, so $$\mu(B_i)\leqslant \mu(f(B_i))/c\leqslant \mu(A_i)/c$$ for each $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$. Fix scalars $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ and let $s=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i1_{A_i}$. Note that $s\circ f=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i1_{B_i}$. For $1\leqslant p<\infty$, calculate $$\|f\|_p^p=\sum_{i=1}^n |c_i|^p\mu(A_i)$$ and $$\|s\circ f\|_p^p=\sum_{i=1}^n |c_i|^p\mu(B_i)\leqslant c^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n |c_i|^p \mu(A_i).$$  Taking $p^{th}$ roots gives $\|s\circ f\|_p\leqslant c^{-1/p}\|f\|_p$.  By density of simple functions, $\|T_f\phi\|_p\leqslant c^{-1/p}\|f\|_p$ for all $f\in L^p(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$.

For the case $p=\infty$, again with $s=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i1_{A_i}$, $$\|s\|_\infty=\max_{i:\mu(A_i)>0}|c_i|,$$ $$\|T_fs\|_\infty=\max_{i:\mu(B_i)>0}|c_i|,$$ and $\|T_fs\|_\infty\leqslant \|s\|_\infty$, since $\{i:\mu(B_i)>0\}\subset \{i:\mu(B_i)>0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The condition $\mu(f(B))\leq c\mu(B)$ for all $B\in\mathcal{B}$ implies that
$$\mu(f^{-1}(B))\leq c\mu(f(f^{-1}(B)))\leq c\mu(B)$$
since $f^{-1}(f(B))\subset B$ for all $B$ and the fact that $f\big(f^{-1}(B)\big)\in \mathcal{B}$ by assumption.

Define the measure $\nu_f=\mu\circ f^{-1}$ on $(X,\mathcal{B})$, that is $\nu_f$ is the [push forward measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) of $\mu$ by $f$. This measure is well defined, and the conditions of the problem imply that
$$\nu_f\leq c\mu$$
operator $T_f$ can be seen as a linear map  $T:L_0(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)\rightarrow L_0(X,\,\mathcal{B},\nu)$ given by $g\mapsto g$,  where $L_0(\mu)$ denotes the same of measurable functions w.r.t the completion of $\mu$. For any nonnegative measurable function $g$,
$$\int g\circ f\,d\mu =\int g \,d(\mu^{-1}\circ f)=\int g\,d\nu_f\leq c\int g\,d\mu$$

- In particular, for any $\phi\in L_p(\mu)$, $0<p<\infty$,
  $$\|T_f\phi\|^p_{L_p(\mu)}=\int |\phi\circ f|^p\,d\mu=\int |\phi|^p\,d\nu_f\leq c\int|\phi|^p\,d\mu=c\|\phi\|^p_{L_p(\mu)}$$
  which shows that $T_f$ is a bounded operator from $L_p(\mu)\rightarrow L_p(\mu)$, with
  $$\|T_f\|\leq c^{1/p}$$
- For $p=\infty$, if $\phi\in L_\infty(\mu)$
  $$\mu(|\phi\circ f|>\alpha)=\nu_f(|\phi|>\alpha)\leq c\mu(|\phi|>\alpha)$$
  Hence $\{\alpha>0:\mu(|\phi|>\alpha)=0\}\subset\{\alpha>0:\nu_f(|\phi|>\alpha)=0\}$ and so,
  \begin{align}
  \|\phi\circ f\|_\infty&=\|\phi\|_{L_\infty(\nu_f)}=\inf\{\alpha>0:\nu_f(|\phi|>\alpha)=0\}\\
  &\leq\inf\{\alpha>0:\mu(|\phi|>\alpha)=0\}=\|\phi\|_{L_\infty(\mu)}
  \end{align}

---

Comment: the main of the push forward measure (a.k.a change of variables) $\nu_f(\cdot)=\mu(f^{-1}(\cdot))$ which states
$$\int f\,d\nu_f=\int g\circ f\, d\mu$$
for all measurable $f\geq0$ is establish in the usual way:

1. It holds for indicator functions: $\int \mathbb{1}_B\circ f\,d\mu=\int\mathbb{1}_{f^{-1}(B))}\,d\mu=\mu(f^{-1}(B))=\int\mathbb{1}_B\,d\nu_f$
2. It extends by linearity to simple functions
3. Extends to any nonnegative measurable function $g$ by monotone convergence: approximate $g$ by a nondecreasing sequence $s_n$ of simple functions.